# fatal error: dcmtk/config/osconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, dcmtk

I am desperately trying, as a CMake newbie to get DCMTK to do stuff. The example I am trying to compile and run is the following:

```
#include "dcmtk/config/osconfig.h"
#include "dcmtk/dcmdata/dctk.h"
#include "dcmtk/dcmdata/dcistrmf.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    OFCondition status;

    /* approach 1 */
    DcmMetaInfo metainfo;
    status = metainfo.loadFile("test.dcm");
    if (status.good())
    {
        OFString sopClassUID, xferUID;
        if (metainfo.findAndGetOFString(DCM_MediaStorageSOPClassUID, sopClassUID).good())
            COUT << "SOP Class UID: " << sopClassUID << OFendl;
        if (metainfo.findAndGetOFString(DCM_TransferSyntaxUID, xferUID).good())
            COUT << "Transfer Syntax UID: " << xferUID << OFendl;
        metainfo.print(COUT);
    }

    /* approach 2 */
    DcmFileFormat fileformat;
    status = fileformat.loadFile("test.dcm", EXS_Unknown, EGL_noChange, DCM_MaxReadLength, ERM_metaOnly);
    if (status.good())
    {
        OFString sopClassUID, xferUID;
        if (fileformat.getMetaInfo()->findAndGetOFString(DCM_MediaStorageSOPClassUID, sopClassUID).good())
            COUT << "SOP Class UID: " << sopClassUID << OFendl;
        if (fileformat.getMetaInfo()->findAndGetOFString(DCM_TransferSyntaxUID, xferUID).good())
            COUT << "Transfer Syntax UID: " << xferUID << OFendl;
        fileformat.print(COUT);
    }

    /* approach 3 */
    fileformat.clear();
    DcmInputFileStream fileStream("test.dcm");
    status = fileStream.status();
    if (status.good())
    {
        /* first, read meta-header */
        fileformat.setReadMode(ERM_metaOnly);
        fileformat.transferInit();
        status = fileformat.read(fileStream);
        if (status.good())
        {
            OFString sopClassUID, xferUID;
            if (fileformat.getMetaInfo()->findAndGetOFString(DCM_MediaStorageSOPClassUID, sopClassUID).good())
                COUT << "SOP Class UID: " << sopClassUID << OFendl;
            if (fileformat.getMetaInfo()->findAndGetOFString(DCM_TransferSyntaxUID, xferUID).good())
                COUT << "Transfer Syntax UID: " << xferUID << OFendl;
            /* then read dataset if certain criteria are met */
            if (sopClassUID == UID_SecondaryCaptureImageStorage)
            {
                fileformat.setReadMode(ERM_autoDetect);
                status = fileformat.read(fileStream);
                if (status.good())
                {
                    fileformat.print(COUT);
                }
            }
        }
        fileformat.transferEnd();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem comes from the upper part of this file. I am aware that as is, in a specific folder, this code will have a building error as it will not find the `dcmtk` folder in the project directory. I have built and installed DCMTK in different folders somewhere else on my drive. I therefore have two folders: `dcmtk-3.6.5-build` and `dcmtk-3.6.5-install`. I know that what I am interested in is in `dcmtk-3.6.5-install/include/`. But when building I get the following error:

```
====================[ Build | test_dcmtk | Debug ]==============================
/snap/clion/139/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/project_dir/test_dcmtk/cmake-build-debug --target test_dcmtk -- -j 38
Scanning dependencies of target test_dcmtk
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/project_dir/test_dcmtk/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: dcmtk/config/osconfig.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "dcmtk/config/osconfig.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/build.make:83: CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:138: test_dcmtk] Error 2
```

As I understand it, I should direct the compiler to the directory where DCMTK is installed. However when I do it, I get a very similar error:

```
====================[ Build | test_dcmtk | Debug ]==============================
/snap/clion/139/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/project_dir/test_dcmtk/cmake-build-debug --target test_dcmtk -- -j 38
Scanning dependencies of target test_dcmtk
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/project_dir/test_dcmtk/main.cpp:2:
/home/dcmtk-3.6.5-install/include/dcmtk/dcmdata/dctk.h:25:10: fatal error: dcmtk/config/osconfig.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include "dcmtk/config/osconfig.h"    /* make sure OS specific configuration is included first */
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/build.make:83: CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/test_dcmtk.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:138: test_dcmtk] Error 2
```

The difference between both errors is in the headers that the compiler is seeking. In the second case, it looks like the compiler does not understand where `osconfig.h` is. As this concerns files from DCMTK installation, it is my understanding that they should work as is, which leads me to the thought that this problem should be solved with CMake.
However I have absolutely no idea ho make thinghs right in my `CMakeLists.txt`... And by this, I mean to say that this file contains

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test_dcmtk)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test_dcmtk main.cpp)
```

And I have absolutely no idea what to write here. Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: "As I understand it, I should direct the compiler to the directory where DCMTK is installed. However when I do it... " - I see no attempt in your code (`CMakeLists.txt`) to point the compiler to the directory where DCMTK headers are. Include directories are usually specified with `include_directories` or `target_include_directories` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - do not use `include_directories` in new projects. One should always prefer `target_include_directories`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DCMTK sadly does not provide correctly exported CMake targets, so you will have to patch around that. I installed DCMTK via [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) and was able to compile your code with this build (after replacing `COUT` with `std::cout` and including `iostream`):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(test_dcmtk)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(DCMTK REQUIRED)

# Wrap the variables that DCMTK sets with a proper imported target
# These three lines ought not to be needed.
# This is a failure on the part of the DCMTK authors.
add_library(DCMTK::DCMTK INTERFACE IMPORTED)
target_link_libraries(DCMTK::DCMTK INTERFACE ${DCMTK_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(DCMTK::DCMTK INTERFACE ${DCMTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Create your executable and link it to the library
add_executable(test_dcmtk main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_dcmtk PRIVATE DCMTK::DCMTK)
```

You should complain to the DCMTK library authors that they don't supply a correct imported target.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem... To replace it with another problem. Now it is telling me it does not find some kind of library that I have no knowledge of: `error while loading shared libraries: liboflog.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Any idea on this matter?

Comment: No, sorry. Vcpkg tends to patch around broken upstreams a bit. Feel free to open another question with details regarding how you built DCMTK. Alternatively, use vcpkg because you should be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling with MSVC? Try to compile with Clang instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33698850)

Comment: DCMTK is made for use with Clang and GNU (it seems like in their documentation). Using Clang solved the issue for me.

Comment: From the question I see that CMake spits out errors about missing includes. By changing the compiler that will not go away. Also according to file paths the error happens on Linux, so MSVC is not the case here. I assume you compile on Windows, and something like the MinGW or MSYS2 environment has fixed the issue?

Comment: I could not compile the config file for some reason, I got the message I needed C++11 or higher, even though i used set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) in my Cmake file.
Changing the compiler stopped the error message for me. Just wanted to throw it out there for someone else in case they have the same issue. Or should I delete the answer?

Comment: To answer the question you need to provide the content of your CMakeLists.txt file. If it's different from the one provided by @alex-reinking, then together with information from your comments it can make a good answer